# C# several LINQ queries in one big LINQ query to the one source

Tags: c#, linq

Please, help me with c# coding since I hven't been coding in c# for couple of years.
I have datatable which contains this data:

**Content of datatable**

[image]

And I have the next classes:

```
public class Warehouse
{
   public int warehouseId;
   public Product[] products;
}
public class Product
{
  public int productId;
  public ProductOrigin[] productOrigins
}
public class ProductOrigin
{
  public int productOriginId;
  public Supplyer[] supplyers;
}
public class Supplyer
{
  public int supplyerId;
  public decimal volume
}
```

(classes were generated according to xsd scheme). I have to fill with data in datatable Warehouse[] warehouses variable. Now I do lots of nested foreach cycles with several queries to the same data. So first i do LINQ query with grouping to get unique warehouses then first foreach then LINQ query to get unique productIds in one warehouse from the same datatable then nested foreach, then another query and nested foreach then the next one (4 or 5 layers in total). The code is huge and looks very aweful. I remember there was a way to gather all needed information in one Linq query to use nested foreach cycles only without requerying data from the same source in every foreach, but don't remeber where I saw it. Could you remind me, please, how can I do that (or maybe there is another way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need the following query:

```cs
var warehouses =
    context.Wharehouse
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(w => w.warehouseId)
    .Select(gw => new Warehouse
    {
        warehouseId = gw.Key,
        products = gw
            .GroupBy(p => p.productId)
            .Select(gp => new Product 
            {
                productId = gp.Key,
                productOrigins = gp
                    .GroupBy(po => po.productOriginId)
                    .Select(gpo => new ProductOrigin
                    {
                        productOriginId = gpo.Key,
                        supplyers = gpo
                            .Select(s => new Supplyer
                            {
                                supplyerId = s.supplyerId,
                                volume = s.Amount
                            })
                            .ToArray()
                    })
                    .ToArray()
            })
            .ToArray()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thnak you very much! That looks very good. These weekends I was reading about LINQ some articles and they made me think of another approach, like from ... in ...groupby from in... so as I've read since I have two from keywords i can use two nested foreach to each from. Plus I so linq construction with let key-word but I haven't understand how let key-word works yet

Comment: `let` keyword just creates additional `Select`. Install Reshaper and you can convert any Query syntax to Lambda syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  the code would be even simpler if you used Lists instead of arrays. :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("warehouseId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductOriginID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SupplyerID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, 200, 1, 123, 25 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, 200, 100035, 123, 6 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, 200, 1, 254, 65 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, 200, 100035, 254, 78 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, 212, 1, 154, 6 });

            Warehouse[] warehouses = Warehouse.ParseWareHouse(dt);


        }
    }
    public class Warehouse
    {
       public int warehouseId { get; set; }
       public Product[] products { get; set; }

       public Warehouse(){}
       public static Warehouse[] ParseWareHouse(DataTable dt)
       {
            var warehouseRows = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("warehouseId"));
            Warehouse[] warehouses = new Warehouse[warehouseRows.Count()];
            int wCount = 0;
            foreach (var warehouseRow in warehouseRows)
            {
                Warehouse warehouse = new Warehouse();
                warehouses[wCount] = warehouse;
                warehouse.warehouseId = warehouseRow.Key;

                new Product(warehouse, warehouseRow.ToList());
                wCount++;
            }
            return warehouses;
       }

    }
    public class Product
    {
      public int productId { get; set; }
      public ProductOrigin[] productOrigins { get; set; }

      public Product() { }
      public Product(Warehouse warehouse, List<DataRow> warehouseRows)
      {
          var productRows = warehouseRows.GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ProductID"));
          warehouse.products = new Product[productRows.Count()];
          int pCount = 0;
          foreach (var productRow in productRows)
          {
              Product product = new Product();
              warehouse.products[pCount] = product;
              product.productId = productRow.Key;

              new ProductOrigin(product, productRow.ToList());
              pCount++;
          }
      }
    }
    public class ProductOrigin
    {
      public int productOriginId { get; set; }
      public Supplyer[] supplyers { get; set; }

      public ProductOrigin() { }
      public ProductOrigin(Product product, List<DataRow> productRows)
      {
          var originRows = productRows.GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ProductOriginID"));
          product.productOrigins = new ProductOrigin[originRows.Count()];
          int oCount = 0;
          foreach (var originRow in originRows)
          {
              ProductOrigin origin = new ProductOrigin();
              product.productOrigins[oCount] = origin;
              origin.productOriginId = originRow.Key;

              new Supplyer(origin, originRow.ToList());
              oCount++;
          }
      }
    }
    public class Supplyer
    {
        public int supplyerId { get; set; }
        public decimal volume { get; set; }

        public Supplyer() { }
        public Supplyer(ProductOrigin origin, List<DataRow> originRows)
        {
            origin.supplyers = new Supplyer[originRows.Count()];
            int sCount = 0;
            foreach (DataRow supplyerRow in originRows)
            {
                Supplyer supplyer = new Supplyer();
                origin.supplyers[sCount] = supplyer;
                supplyerId = supplyerRow.Field<int>("SupplyerID");
                supplyer.volume = supplyerRow.Field<decimal>("Amount"); 

                sCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree it would be easier but classes were generated by xsd scheme so I don't wanna change anything there according to my skills.

Comment: XML serialization doesn't care if a property is an array or a list.  It still passes the schema.