# Could use some help optimizing this data grouping

Tags: c#, linq

It's been a long time and I'm trying to optimize some code so I don't have to look at 4 nested for loops. I'm working with a set of data that is structured something like this

```
[
  [
    {
      Key1: Value1,
      ...
      Key2: [{
         ...
         Key3: {
            Key4: {
               Key5: Value2,
            },
            Key6: {
               Key7: Value3,
            },
            ...
         }
      }]
    }
    ...
  ]
]
```

Apologies for the shabby representation. I can't share an actual sample of the data. What I need is a collection that is grouped by several fields. Currently, the code looks like this

```
foreach (var collection in response.Property1.Collections)
{
   var firstGroups = collection.GroupBy(items => items.Key1);

   foreach (var group in firstGroups)
   {
     var secondGroups = group.GroupBy(items => items.Key2.FirstOrDefault().Key3.Key4.Key5);
                    
     foreach(var secondGroup in secondGroups)
     {
        var thirdGroups= secondGroup.GroupBy(items =>  items.Key2.FirstOrDefault()?.Key3.Key6.Key7);

       foreach(var thirdGroup in thirdGroups)
       {
         yield return new ResultGroup
         {
           GroupKey= thirdGroup.Key,
           Collection = thirdGroup,
           ...
         };
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I'm unfortunately stuck with the source data. I also don't have the luxury to remap the data upstream to allow for better transformation here. I really don't like these nested loops and am open to ideas!

Comment: what does your function / enumerator output? in the context of your source data. or what is the desired output / structure?

Comment: @GlennFerrie If I used baseball cards as an example, the source data would be something like a collection of different baseball cards. The top level would be the player. In each player collection is a list of different versions of that player that have different variations. The ResultGroup.Collection would be a list of player versions grouped by things like year, condition, and quantity. Really hard to explain in words and not allowed to show the real schema.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66942017/10646316

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That looks good except I'd need to add some new models to represent the intermediary forms. Was hoping to find something with minimal changes. I know it's a long shot but this is a good reference, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to put every foreach in a separate method, and let these methods call each other. If you use meaningful names this wouldn't be a problem.

Advantages: It would be easier to understand what each procedure would do, easier to unit test them, easier to reuse, and maintain.

You start with a sequence of collections:

```
IEnumerable<Libraries> Libraries = ...

foreach (var library in libraries)
{
    IEnumerable<Book> books = GetBooks(library);
    foreach (var book in books) 
        yield return book;
}

IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(Library library)
{
    // FirstGroup: make groups of departments in the Library:
    IEnumerable<int, Department> departmentGroups = library.GroupBy(...);
    IEnumerable<Book> books = GetBooks(departmentGroup)
    foreach (var book in books)
       yield return book;
}

IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(IGrouping<int, Department> departmentGroups)
{
    // SecondGroup: group the bookcases in the departments by location code
    IEnumerable<...> bookCasesInSameLocation = departmentGroup.GroupBy(...);
    IEnumerable<Book> books = GetBooks(bookCasesInSameLocation)
    foreach (var book in books)
       yield return book;
}
```

And so on, this also works for other LINQ statements than GroupBy

```
IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(IEnumerable<...> bookCaseLocations)
{
    IEnumerable<...> bookShelves = bookCaseLocations.Where(...)
        .Where(...)
        .Select(...);
    IEnumerable<Book> books = GetBooks(bookShelves)
    foreach (var book in books)
       yield return book;
}
```

And so on, until the last level:

```
IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(BookShelve bookShelve)
{
     foreach (Book book in bookShelve.Books.Where(...).Select(...))
     {
         yield return book;
     }
}
```

The challenge is of course to define proper names and classes for your intermediate results. But IMHO, if you can't find a proper name, are you sure that you know what every GroupBy and other LINQ statement represents?

Comment: Thank you! It's a start. I'd be adding more bloat to an already bloated file but it might be necessary. Pushing for a whole re-write haha

Comment: I created them as extension methods, so it would be one file with about 5 extension methods. The most positive about this approach is that you can unit test them individually